# I tried write a program for finding GCD using a function.Why is this code not working?

Tags: c, function

This is the code i have written so far, i can't find any logical redundancies . Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>   

int gcd(int,int);  
void main()

{
int a, b, c;
printf("enter 2 num\n" );
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);  
printf("gcd of %d and %d is %d",a,b,gcd(a,b));
}

int gcd(int a,int b)  
{
int i, c;
for(i=0;i<a&&i<b;i++)
{
    if((a%i==0)&&(b%i==0))
        
    c=i;
    
}
return c;

}
```

I am not getting any output.
Input: 25, 75

ps. my first question

edit: thanks for the help , i did a silly mistake and intialized i=0, so my program crashed .

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What specific problem are you having with the code you've posted?

Comment: it is not showing any output.

Comment: Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: Try `for (int i=1` instead of `for (int i=0`

Answer (score 1):

The function you are using is wrong unless my assumption is false.
can you specify which algorithm are you using for the function.
If you want you can refer to the below Euclidean GCD algorithm-based function attached below.

```
int euclid(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0) {
     return x;
    } else if (x >= y && y > 0) {
       return euclid(y, (x % y));
  } 
}
```

FULL PROGRAM :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int euclid(int, int);
int main()
{
  int m, n, gcd;
  clock_t start,end;
  double cpu_time_used; 
  printf("\nEnter two numbers to find gcd using Euclidean algorithm: ");
  scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
  start=clock(); 
  gcd = euclid(m,n);
  end=clock();
  cpu_time_used=((double) (end-start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  if (gcd){
    printf("\nThe GCD of %d and %d is %d", m, n, gcd);
    printf("\nGCD Function took %lf Seconds to Execute\n\n",cpu_time_used);
  }
  else
    printf("\nInvalid input\n");
  return 0;
 }


int euclid(int x, int y)
{
  if (y == 0) {
      return x;
  } else if (x >= y && y > 0) {
      return euclid(y, (x % y));
  }
 }
```

Comment: I mean there is no error , but it is not showing any output.

Comment: The code shared above is perfectly working with the output. I think there is some issue with your IDE/Complier, please rectify that. Try with any online compiler and check.

Comment: i got the bug, i was doing % operation with i=0, so my program crashed. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: A pleasure to help. Happy Coding!...

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, it crashed because you are doing division by 0 on the first round of your for loop. You initialized i to 0, then used it with `a` and `b` to do the `%` operation. So, if `a` were 10, that would be like "divide 10 by 0 and get the remainder". You can't divide a number by 0 since it's undefined.

The other person's function is good too. Here's a version I wrote once that is iterative and not recursive. The stuff in the beginning before the while loop at the bottom is just set up to deal with negative numbers and make sure n1 is always greater than n2. The actual algorithm is the while loop.

```
int gcd(int numerator, int denominator) {
    int remainder, temp, n1, n2;
    if (numerator < 0) numerator *= -1;
    if (denominator < 0) denominator *= -1;
    if (numerator > denominator) {
        n1 = numerator;
        n2 = denominator;
    }
    else {
        n1 = denominator;
        n2 = numerator;
    }

    remainder = n1 % n2;
    while (remainder > 0) {
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = remainder;
        remainder = n1 % n2;
    }

    return n2;
}
```

Comment: most useful comment brother! Thank you. I lost my temper while trying to find the bug.

Comment: I know you're new to programming so here's some advice. For problems like these, use an IDE with debugging capabilities (for example, I use Microsoft Visual Studio), or if you're working in Linux you can use the GDB debugger. Using a debugger will help you solve these issues. For example, if you set a breakpoint and then went step by step, your program would have stopped at the division by 0 part and an error message would have displayed informing you of the problem.

Comment: i will keep it in mind.